# How to fix InvalidMappingException

Tags: hibernate

I am getting this error from the web application I'm working right now:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/mygwtapp/shared/DTO/Account.hbm.xml
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.mygwtapp.client.service.UserService.createUser(com.mygwtapp.shared.DTO.Account)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Here is my [Account.java](http://pastebin.com/gDuhUugA)

Here is my [Account.hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml](http://pastebin.com/urMnfRK9)

Comment: Can u extend the exception? Is that all you get from the log?

Comment: I figured out the solution. I have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is missing a JAR file: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`

Which is needed to be in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder

And that the Account.hbm.xml class name tag:

```
<class name="com.mygwtapp.DTO.Account" table="account">
```

Should be:

```
<class name="com.mygwtapp.shared.DTO.Account" table="account">
```